# How do I retrieve previous iTunes purchases

Tags: itunes

I wish to download previous iTunes purchases on my iPhone, but there is nothing showing up in my purchases.  When I go direct and search on iTunes for the music I have downloaded it says I have purchased but wont let me re download.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can download previous purchases from the App Store, iBooks Store and iTunes store. The following Apple article outlines what you need to do depending on the store and platform you are using.

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2519

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps..
On an iPhone or iPod touch

```
1.Open the iTunes Store app.
2.At the bottom of the screen, tap More > Purchased > Music.
3.Tap "Not on This iPhone" or "Not on This iPod."
4.Find the song that you want to download, then tap it.
5.Tap the Download icon to the right of the title. Your song downloads to your device.
```

Answer (score -1):

Generally you can't re-download purchased songs from the iTunes Store, but [this link](http://www.theinternetpatrol.com/yes-you-can-download-all-of-your-itunes-purchases-again/) suggests that there might be a way to do it after all.

> [...]But first, make absolutely sure that you don’t have any copies,
>   anywhere. It’s only prudent.
>
> Once you are really sure that those iTunes songs are gone, here’s what
>   to do:
>
> 1. Open the iTunes Store on your device.
> 2. Make sure you are signed in with the same account used for the original purchase.
> 3. Tap Purchased from the bottom navigation bar.
> 4. From the Purchased tab, tap the artist name for the content you intend to download again.
> 5. Once you’ve located the music you are looking for, tap the download button.
>
> (If you want to download all songs from an album that you’ve
>   purchased, click on the button to swith to the “Album” view.)

This may or may not work for you, but it's worth a try.